# Best approach for [back][next] form submitting

Tags: forms

I've been doing a **[back][next]** to **[finish]** set of forms for user input fields, think of it like a questionnaire for user info where the user can still go back to the previous pages to update their info.. until it reaches the end of the pages to [finish]

I've done this before (hardcoded) but my code is too long and all the debugging gave me a headache. My first approach was:

- Use a PHP case to find out which phase/step the user is in now
- If the user clicks on [next], the page variable appends a +1 to the page count
- If the user clicks on [back], the page var deducts -1 to the page count, until it reaches
  [finish]
- If the user leaves the page for some reason and comes back to it, the session/cookie saved fills in the form values and which phase/step the user is in

This method of mine isn't very dynamic as the php case is hardcoded to a set of page numbers & phases, if the client wants to add another page; that can be a problem.

I'm new to Drupal; maybe Drupal already has some part of the API that makes this [back][update][next][finish] easier, or a easier way to store cookies? If by PHP only, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use the [Form API](http://drupal.org/node/37775) for forms, unless you really wanted to use the [Webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform). The learning curve it steeper but you gain more maintainability (everything is in code from the start) and flexibility. You can create multisteps form with the API. See [form_example_wizard.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example--form_example_wizard.inc/7) and *[Drupal 7 multistep forms using variable functions](http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/drupal-7-multistep-forms-using-variable-functions)* (also with [Drupal 6](http://www.benjeavons.com/multi-step-forms-drupal-6-using-variable-functions)) for examples. Another solution, is to [use the CTools' wizard API](http://www.nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6).

Comment: The Examples project (http://drupal.org/project/examples) has a form example with multistep form demonstrations for D6 and D7.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the webform module like so: http://drupal.org/node/324779